# Azure VM image version creation fail

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm creating a VM image version, but it keeps failing with this message.

> Failed to update replication for VM image version
> 'XXXXXcomputegallery/XXXXX/0.0.1'. Error: Source was not
> found:
> 'ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/XXXXXXX_OsDisk_1_2a293f0ade0a4bb583eedb0984dbcabe'>XXXXXXX_OsDisk_1_2a293f0ade0a4bb583eedb0984dbcabe'.
> Please make sure the source exists.

I searched this issue online, and I suspect it's because the VM and the disk are in North Central US and the selected instance details region is East US on the VM image version creation page.

But the instance details region is greyed out and I cannot change to North Central or to any other regions.

The resource group and the compute gallery I selected are also the North Central Resource group...I really don't know why I can only select East US.

I have enough quota for that VM, so I don't think it's the quota issue.

Creating an image version from the snapshot works fine without any errors.

What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same in my environment I got the same error like below:

[image]

Created a virtual machine and disk in North Central US when I try to create vm image version it shows Eastus and greyed-out.

[image]

> **it's possible that the region is fixed because of selection of the compute gallery. Some compute galleries may be associated with a specific region, and as a result, you may not be able to change the> region when creating a VM image version.**

To resolve this issue:

***In portal, under search -> Azure compute gallery -> click on Vm image definition -> Add version***

[image]

[image]

Now, I can able to select any region without grey-out and selected North central us like below:

[image]

***Deployed Vm image version successfully like below:***

[image]